Help, Estate Sale Mystery Cactus
Got this at an estate sale in Belen, NM, and can’t figure out what it is. Any ideas?


Google reverse image search indicates it could be a Tephrocactus, albeit a bit more shriveled than the pictures indicate. Maybe needs water?  I'm not a cactus expert though.
